# How to tell Jackson Library to replace null value fields with an empty object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to tell Jackson Library to replace null value fields with an empty object ?

for example: I have the following class

```
public class Message {
    private Info info;
    private String data;
}
```

I do the following

```
Message msg = new Message(null, "abc");
objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(msg)
```

When I deserialize I want to get the following output

```
{"info": {}, "data": "abc"}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I guess that's **invalid** JSON

Comment: @radbrawler How is it invalid JSON?

Comment: check on any online JSON validator

Comment: @radbrawler - it looks ok to me.

Comment: its ok ofter editing.!